# C code - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

I'm trying to compile my c code, but I always get Segmentation fault after I execute my program. Here is part of my code:

```
LINE_LENGTH=300

struct clip {
  int views;
  char *user;
  char *id;
  char *title;
  char *duration;
  struct clip *next;
} *head;
```

my main function, where argv[1] is my csv file

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int n;
   head = build_a_lst(*(argv+1));
   return 0;}
```

The rest of my code

```
struct clip *build_a_lst(char *fn) {
  FILE *fp;
  struct clip *hp;
  char *fields[5];
  char line[LINE_LENGTH];
  int cnt=0,i;
  hp=NULL;

  fp=fopen(fn,"r");
  if(fp=NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  while(fgets(line,LINE_LENGTH,fp)!=NULL){
    split_line(fields,line);//fields has five values stored
    hp=append(hp,fields);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      free(fields[i]);
      fields[i]=NULL;
    }
  }

  return hp;
}


void split_line(char **fields,char *line) {
  int i=0;
  char *token, *delim;
  delim = ",\n";

  token=strtok(line,delim);//ok line
  for(;token!=NULL;i++){

    fields[i]=malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(fields[i],token);
    token=strtok(NULL,delim);
  }

}

struct clip *append(struct clip *hp,char **five) {
  struct clip *cp,*tp;

  tp=malloc(sizeof(struct clip));
  tp->views=atoi(five[1]);

  tp->user=malloc(strlen(five[0]+1));
  tp->duration=malloc(strlen(five[2]+1));
  tp->id=malloc(strlen(five[3]+1));
  tp->title=malloc(strlen(five[4]+1));

  strcpy(tp->user,five[0]);
  strcpy(tp->duration,five[2]);
  strcpy(tp->id,five[3]);
  strcpy(tp->title,five[4]);

  cp=hp;
  while(cp!=NULL)
    cp=cp->next;

  cp->next=tp;
  hp=cp;

  return hp;
}
```

According to some articles segmentation fault is caused by trying to read or write an illegal memory location. And since I am allocating memory in different parts of my code, the problem should be there. Can someone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try run with gdb and paste the backtrace (bt)

Comment: Paste in the minimum that can be used to verify the problem.

Comment: There's at least one problem which would be caught by having warnings enabled. Use `-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang* (something else for other compilers).

Comment: Lets start with the very first line: `LINE_LENGTH=300`, is missing a semi-colon, and, without further context, is almost certainly a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

1. `if(fp=NULL)` should be `if(fp == NULL)`
2. `char *fields[5];` should be `char *fields[5] = {NULL};`
3. `for(;token!=NULL;i++){` should be `for(; token != NULL && i < 5; i++){`
4. These:

   ```
   tp->user=malloc(strlen(five[0]+1));
   tp->duration=malloc(strlen(five[2]+1));
   tp->id=malloc(strlen(five[3]+1));
   tp->title=malloc(strlen(five[4]+1));
   ```

   should be

   ```
   tp -> user     = malloc(strlen(five[0]) + 1);
   tp -> duration = malloc(strlen(five[2]) + 1);
   tp -> id       = malloc(strlen(five[3]) + 1);
   tp -> title    = malloc(strlen(five[4]) + 1);
   ```
5. You don't `free` several of the `malloc`ed memory.

Comment: the first one is easily captured if he had enabled warnings

Comment: Thank you for pointing out those problems. I updated my code but I still have the segmentation fault message

Comment: @JOrG It would be easier to help if you posted a [mcve]. And don't edit your question such that it makes all the answers meaningless. You can figure out the issue by using a debugger.